# Расстановка запятых в указании места работы

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, топонимика

> Администрация города Ликино-Дулево, Орехово-Зуевского муниципального района, Московской области, заместитель руководителя администрации (место работы, занимаемая должность).

Нужны ли запятые?

Answer (score 2):

Администрация города Ликино-Дулево  Орехово-Зуевского муниципального района Московской области, заместитель руководителя администрации (место работы, занимаемая должность).

При указании места работы названия ***город, район, область*** неоднородны, поэтому запятые не ставятся.